# Is there a way to fire onPaste event on React Material <TableRow> in internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html, internet-explorer, web

I'm designing a data table which needs to provide functionality of being able to paste data rows copied from excel. However, the  onPaste event won't fire in Internet Explorer.  I was able to achieve this and fetch clipboard data in chrome.

```
<Table className={classes.table} aria-labelledby="tableTitle">
            <EnhancedTableHead
              numSelected={selected.length}
              order={order}
              orderBy={orderBy}
              onSelectAllClick={this.handleSelectAllClick}
              onRequestSort={this.handleRequestSort}
              rowCount={data.length}
            />
            <TableBody onPaste={event => this.handlePaste(ClipboardEvent)}>
              {stableSort(data, getSorting(order, orderBy))
                .map(n => {
                  const isSelected = this.isSelected(n.id);
                  return (
                    <TableRow
                      hover
                      onClick={event => this.handleClick(event, n.id)}
                      role="checkbox"
                      aria-checked={isSelected}
                      tabIndex={-1}
                      key={n.id}
                      selected={isSelected}
                    >
                      <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                        <Checkbox checked={isSelected} />
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row" padding="none">
                        {n.udf}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{n.ticker}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{n.transType}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{n.qty}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{n.portfolio}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  );
                })}
              {emptyRows > 0 && (
                <TableRow style={{ height: 49 * emptyRows }}>
                  <TableCell colSpan={6} />
                </TableRow>
              )}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation than you can find that paste event is supported and compatibility for OnPaste event is unknown.

I made a test with OnPaste event and find that event is working in Internet Explorer.

Issue is Clip board data is not supported in Internet Explorer.

So you will not be able to access the data using it.

[image]

Tested code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" onpaste="myFunction()" value="Try to paste something in here" size="40">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You pasted text!";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Output in Internet Explorer 11:

[image]

References:

(1) [HTMLElement​.onpaste](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/onpaste)

(2) [Element: paste event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event)

As an alternative, you can try to refer example in link below may help you to solve the issue.

[Cross-browser JavaScript Copy and Paste](https://dzone.com/articles/cross-browser-javascript-copy-and-paste)